# ASP.Net Application deployment process

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

I am building an application in c#, webforms using sqlserver.
I need to deploy the project to a staging server daily.

I want to know whats best way to deploy a website and what are steps?
And can we automate this process?

Comment: You might want to specify if this is a website or WAP project template... people use the term "website" loosely when talking ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Walkthrough: Publishing a Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt.aspx):

> You have the following options for copying the Web site:
>
> - Copy to a folder on the local computer.
> - Use a UNC share to copy to a shared folder that is on another computer on the network.
> - Use FTP to copy to a server.
> - Use the HTTP protocol to copy to a server that has FrontPage Server Extensions (FPSE) installed on it.

For automatic publish your should read about the [Continuous intergation](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use [JetBrains TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity), there's a free version of it and it might have a bit of a learning curve for you.

But this is a pretty broad question, there are tons of ways of doing this; from using batch files and MSBuild, to build servers like TeamCiry, CruiseControl.Net, or Microsoft's Team System.

Answer (score 0):

You should find all the info you need here on Vishal Joshi's new blog post on the topic. They are only now starting to document this properly:

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2011/07/documenting-key-end-to-end-deployment.html